# UrlFetchApp.fetch - need HTTP response status

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to obtain the status *message* of the response to a POST to a rest service via:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(<url>, <params>);
```

I need the status description as reported by the server which does not appear to be available as part of the [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) object returned by the fetch method.

I can get the status code using:

```
response.getResponseCode();
```

But no luck on the message associated with it. I have wrapped the fetch call in a try/catch block, but the error message returned using that method is an error message provided by the spreadsheet service, not the original, raw status description from the server response.

Any ideas on how to obtain this piece of information, most appreciated.

Comment: Add the google-apps-script tag?

Answer (score 1):

The associated message from the service should be available in `HTTPResponse.getContentText()`. You'll need to pass the optional parameter `muteHttpExceptions` set to `true` in the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` request to prevent an exception from being thrown.

Comment: 'HTTPResponse.getContentText()' returns nothing even when I 'muteHttpExceptions'. The HTTP status is part of the HTTP response - not a header and not in the body.